# How many different pairs of advisors can be selected for a seven-story building from $12$ male candidates and $15$ female candidates?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm stuck on this question:

"At a certain college, the housing office has decided to appoint, for each floor, one male and one female residential advisor. How many different pairs of advisors can be selected for a seven-story building from $12$ male candidates and $15$ female candidates?"

OK, so would i use permutation?
I cant seem to figure out what's the $n$ and what's the $r$... Or combinations? or something else?

Comment: None.  There are no female candidates. :)

Comment: oops! 12 males 15 females

Answer (score 2):

I assume there are $12$ male and $15$ female. Consider the first floor. It needs one male and one female. Number of ways to make this choice is $12 \times 15$. Now lets look at the second floor. Number of ways to make this choice is $11 \times 14$. Hence, the total number of ways is
$$(12 \times 15) \times (11 \times 14) \times (10 \times 13) \times (9 \times 12) \times (8 \times 11) \times (7 \times 10) \times (6 \times 9)$$

Comment: Oh, ok.. makes sense. What is the called?

Comment: That seems to be the best way to interpret the question. I'd be happier if they'd said "How many different sets of seven pairs of advisors ..." or is that the only way to interpret the question?

Comment: @Itzel It can be written as a permutation. Note that it can be written as $\dfrac{12!}{5!} \cdot \dfrac{15!}{8!} = P(12,7) \cdot P(15,7)$, where $P(n,r)$ is the number of ways of permuting $r$ out of $n$ objects.

Comment: @user17762 where do the 5 and 8 come from?

Comment: @user17762 would it not be (12x15)+(11x14)+.....?
when i multiply them i get a really big exponential number...

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is wrong for anyone looking here. You are supposed to add them, not multiply them. So:

$12*15+11*14+10*13+9*12+8*11+7*10+6*9=784$.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  You add when two events cannot occur simultaneously; you multiply when they can occur at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

We have to **choose** $7$ males out of $12$ males **and** $7$ females out of $15$ females.

Here **choose** and **and** mean combination and multiply respectively.

hence answer is ${}^{12}C_7 \times {}^{15}C_7$ which is $6435 \times 792$
which equals to $5096520$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your answer is incorrect since it matters which advisor is placed on which floor.